# Color selection in R (lighting setup)

Tags: r, colors

Is there any function in R for Darking/lighting setup. For example I want to have a very light greet color close to blue color (for my boxplots) but I do not know how to make it. I tried to choose color from this selection http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf  but I want to make the color lighter than this selection.

Comment: Searched CRAN for "color" (and maybe "colour")? https://cran.r-project.org/

Comment: You can specify colors in R with RGB hex values. Use whatever program you want to find your color then find the hex value for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lighten colours by increasing their transparency. The `alpha` function from the `scales` package lets you do this:

```
library(scales)
windows()
plot(1:10, 1:10, col = alpha("green", 1:10/10), #10%, 20%, 30%.. transparency
     cex = 4, pch = 16)
```